# Excel Cross referencing lists

Tags: excel

What I would like is a formula to search column A and return a result from column J. Simple!

Not quite.

In column A is a list of names, some with first and last and some with middle names. I would like to search Column A for cells containing "John" and "Doe" and receive the result for a cell containing "John A Doe"

Comment: column j???????

Comment: Sorry I'd like the result from the same row in column J.
Eg. cell A5 contains "John A Doe" and so the formula returns whatever is in cell J5

Comment: Where is the John and Doe that you are searching for? is it in some other column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wildcard (*) and `Match` to find the row your value is on.  You can then use `INDEX` to return the value from that row in column J.

If cell `C1` contains *John Doe* you can substitute the space for a wildcard, add a wildcard at the start and end and search:
`MATCH("*" & SUBSTITUTE($C$1," ","*") & "*",$A:$A,0)`

returning the value from column J using `INDEX`:
`=INDEX($J:$J,MATCH("*" & SUBSTITUTE($C$1," ","*") & "*",$A:$A,0))`

If cell `C1` contains *John* and `D1` contains *Doe*:
`MATCH("*" & C1 & "*" & D1 & "*",$A:$A,0)`

returning the value from column J:
`=INDEX($J:$J,MATCH("*" & C1 & "*" & D1 & "*",$A:$A,0))`

Comment: Wildcards, now I feel stupid! I don't understand how $c$1 enters a wild card in between "John Doe" ? and I can't get that formula to work. However, the problem is solved, thank you

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE($C$1," ","*")` enters the wild card in the space in "John Doe", so if $C$1 contains "John Allen Doe" the substitute will show "John/*Allen/*Doe".  The `Match` will then use that to return the row number (providing  you start the reference on row 1) and `Index` returns the value from another column.... `INDEX(J:J,3)` returns the third cell in column J (J3).   Erm... in a comment how do you escape the * (ignore the backslash)?